# Script cannot read file from directory

Tags: php, exif

I have a script which extracts Exif data from a photo stored in a given directory and then displays the image with the exif information on a web page.

Here's the part of the script which retrieves the exif data, this example being a hard coded image:

```
    $Image = 'original/raleighbike.JPG';

    echo "$Image";

    $exif = exif_read_data($Image, 0, true);
```

This works and the exif data is displayed.
(The 'echo' is just there to verify that the correct image is being setup for retrieval in the next part - which is where I have a problem.)

I now use the same script to fetch the exif from an image uploaded in a previous script and stored in the same directory.
The upload script sets a variable ($Image9) containing the image name and location and the exif extraction script now looks like this:

```
$Image = $Image9;

echo "$Image";

$exif = exif_read_data($Image, 0, true);
```

The problem I have is that the 'echo' prints the correct image name and location, but the exif data is empty and the error log reads:

```
[02-Apr-2013 18:45:29 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data() [<a href='function.exif-read-data'>function.exif-read-data</a>]: Unable to open file in /home2/webi8726/public_html/domain.com/sqlsidebar/displayexif.php on line 23
```

Line 23 is the last line in the quoted section above.

I cannot understand why the hard coded image is opened with no problem, but the image identified by the variable can't be opened - even though the variable contains the correct info and is pointing to the same file which is hard coded.

Can anyone suggest why the problem is occurring.

---

OK- played about some more today and this is what I find.

1 - In the script that uploads and stores the jpg I changed the variable it sets to $photo.
$photo should contain the name of the jpg and the directory it is stored in. I also set a different variable called $thumb which contains the name and location of a thumbnail of the jpg which is created and stored by the upload script.

2 - I changed the exif extraction script to use the $photo variable to create a variable called $Image which is used at various points in the script after exif extraction - for example to fetch and display the image as well store the image details in a sql database.

3 - I set some 'echo' commands to verify the contents of the variables, as well as too confirm the file exists.

This is the script code now:

```
    $Image = $photo;

    echo "$photo";

    echo $Image;

    echo file_exists($Image) ? 'ok' : ' image file not found';

    echo file_exists($photo) ? 'ok' : '  photo file not found';

    echo $thumb;

    echo file_exists($thumb) ? 'ok' : '  thumb file not found';

    $exif = exif_read_data($photo, 0, true);
```

The resulting echo string displays the following

```
original/raleighbike.jpg - content of variable $photo (correct)
original/raleighbike.jpg - content of variable $Image (correct)
image file not found - when checking for the file in $Image (incorrect, file does exist)
photo file not found - when checking for the file in $photo (incorrect, file does exist)
thumb file not found - when checking for the file in $thumb (incorrect, file does exist)
thumbnail/thumb_raleighbike.jpg
```

So it would appear that if a file is hardcoded the script is able to physically locate it, but if a file/s are specified as variables, the script cannot find them.

Has anyone any ideas as to why this might happen - I surely can't be the only one to ever experience this issue ;-(

Comment: Your code says `$Image9` but your description `$Image99`. which is it? Did you do basic debugging to see what the contents of `$Image` are after you set it?

Comment: Sorry - typo - it is $Image9. When you say debugging,  I put the 'echo' in to print the content of $Image and in both cases (hardcoded and variable) the detail is correct - ie pointing to the correct location/image. What stumps me is why the 'exif_read_data' cannot access the directory/image, whilst a hardcoded instruction does.

Comment: Is the path contained in `$Image9`relative or absolute? Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: I have checked the file permissions on the image directory - 777. The path shown for both hardcoded and variable are the same = 'original/image.jpg'

Comment: and the permissions for the file itself are also correct?

Comment: The file permissions are 644 (OK for read All) - which should be OK as the file can be read by the script when it is hardcoded.

Comment: try `echo file_exists($Image) ? 'ok' : 'file not found';`

Comment: I have further info which I have posted as an answer to include code.